# Programming on a remote machine [Eclipse - ruby]

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Has someone used any add-on on eclipse to develop on a remote machine ?

I am having to ssh through the terminal and copy paste the eclipse code
to run it on a remote host that has the necessary permissions for the
task. I am wondering if I can do that on eclipse from my ubuntu desktop

Thanks!

Edit:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS suggested by Shawn Bower works as far as the OS is concerned

Q] Unfortunately eclipse can open the script on remote mounted FS, however it doesnt show up in the Script explorer or in run Configurations. "Invalid working directory"

Q] Is there a way to sudo su when I am using SSHFS.

To give a perspective:
Normally I log into the remote user as myself@remote and then sudo su - powerUser and then use that to run my ruby scripts. Unfortunately I do not have the pswd for powerUser.

So now though I can edit the scripts on eclipse after using SSHFS , I still cant run them as powerUSer.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into using sshfs?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS.  It will allow you to mount the remote file system so it acts as a local filesystem.  Then you can just point eclipse at the local path and edit away.  I use this for a bunch of sites.

Comment: thnx Shawn Bower !. I would appreciate if you can also please check an updated question about running SSHFS as a different user ?

Comment: Thre isnt a way to remote sudo with sshfs, you would still have to login into the remote machine to do that/